# How to get image size from a canvas?

Tags: php, image, gd

Is it possible to get the image size in pixels from a canvas?

E.g. I know I can achieve it getting the size from the image directly:

```
list($width, $height) = @getimagesize($_FILES['inputFieldName']['tmp_name'])
```

but I want to get it from a canvas. E.g.:

```
$canvas = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);
//Get image size from $canvas
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$canvas = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);
$width = imagesx($canvas);
$height = imagesy($canvas);
```

Details at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesx.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesy.php